# Command: `react-native run-android` hangs at "info Starting JS server..."

Tags: android, react-native

Picture of hang in terminal

[image: Picture of hang in terminal]

Just getting started with react native. I've gone through the instructions  [React-Native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started.html) and have set up my android emulator, got all that stuff good to go.

I used `npx react-native init auth` to start a project where I hook up some authentication in RN.

Everything was going well until I ran the command `react-native run-android` and now it just keeps hanging when it gets to "Starting JS server..." and doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compile a react-native Android app without using packager:

> react-native run-android --no-packager

After, start packager in another terminal session to bundle js:

> react-native start

Answer (score 0):

open a new tab in terminal and execute this command

```
react-native start
```

it should be starting the js server